# chart catergory label will only rotate from the center?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am just starting to learn EXT JS and I've tried combing through the tutorials but don't seem to find much luck with my problem. My issue is that I have a bar chart, and I wanted to rotate the labels to allow for more space. I can rotate them fine, but it appears that the point of rotation is based on the middle of the label. I'd prefer for the end of the label to line up with the mark for that specific column.

Here's a picture if that didn't make sense:

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

It seems like what I want to achieve is a pretty standard thing, but I can't seem to find much about the issue.

snippet of code:

```
{
  xtype        : 'cartesian',
  store        : 'Store1',
  height       : 350,
  width        : 390,
  flipXY       : true,
  axes         : [
      {
         type     : 'category',
         position : 'left',
         label    : {
             rotation : {
                 degrees : -15
             }    
         }
    },
    {
       type     : 'numeric',
       position : 'bottom'
      }
    ],
    series : [
       {
          type    : 'bar',
          xField  : 'cName',
          yField  : 'cNumber',
          colors  : ['#99CCFF'],
          label   : {
              display : 'outside',
              field   : 'cNumber'
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `textAlign: 'end'`, change the `label` config to:

```
label: {
    textAlign: 'end',
    rotation: {
        degrees: -15
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

After playing around with the label config, hope this is what your looking for:

```
label: {
    textAlign: 'end',
    textBaseline: 'hanging',
    x: -10,
    y: -10,
    rotation: {
        degrees: -15,
        centerX: -5
    }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uea

Comment: That works perfect when there is no rotation set, it connects to the dash on the column. However when I set the label rotation it separates again, almost identical to the picture I originally posted. Any idea why that is? or what else I can try? I feel like you're answer is so close, and maybe I'm missing something very small to get it to work.

Comment: @WhitneyKing: Can you set up a fiddle with an example?

Comment: I've never done one before. Hopefully this saved correctly: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ue4